# Dapper won't install on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, dapper

Adding Dapper to Xamarin iOS project is giving me NuGet installation errors because it apparently misses some target assemblies.

> Adding Dapper... Downloading Dapper 1.50.0... Installing 'Dapper
>   1.50.0'. Added file 'Dapper.dll' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/net40'. Added file 'Dapper.xml' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/net40'. Added
>   file 'Dapper.dll' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/net45'. Added file
>   'Dapper.xml' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/net45'. Added file
>   'Dapper.dll' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/net451'. Added file
>   'Dapper.xml' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/net451'. Added file
>   'Dapper.dll' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/netstandard1.3'. Added file
>   'Dapper.xml' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0/lib/netstandard1.3'. Added file
>   'Dapper.1.50.0.nupkg' to folder 'Dapper.1.50.0'.
>
> Successfully installed 'Dapper 1.50.0'.
>
> Adding 'Dapper 1.50.0' to iOS. Could not install package 'Dapper
>   1.50.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Did anyone found any workaround to add Dapper to Xamarin iOS Project?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be having a fundamental architecture misunderstanding. If you are to access anything other than a local database such as SQL Lite, that should be done over REST or something similar, reaching a web service endpoint. That service will then do the database access and possibly use Dapper.

In any event, the message is clear - there is no Dapper release compatible with iOS. You may try getting the source and create your own assemblies, but it may simply not be feasible.

Comment: Dapper is a micro-ORM which works with every ADO .NET provider, so it doesn't matter if it's the web service who access the database or the mobile application. In my case, i'll use it to work against SQLite so it fits perfectly fine. Anyways, Do you know if there is any workaround to implement it with the Xamarin platform?

Comment: You should be able to grab the source and add it to your solution, instead of relying on the published NuGet packages.

Comment: Add the Dapper Source file in your project or compile it and create your own nuget package